# Append paths to loadpath

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to append a path to the 'loadpath'? I know that I can do `set loadpath "path1":"path2"`, but I want to be able to append paths in different config files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append an existing `set loadpath path1:path2:...` you have to set the `GNUPLOT_LIB` environment variable which is always appended to the loadpath. As far as I know this is the only way to replicate the behavior you're looking for. You can debug with `show loadpath`.

See: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/gnuplot_cvs.pdf

Comment: I know of the GNUPLOT_LIB environment variable. But I was asking about appending paths from a config file. Like if you have a config file in your loadpath, you load that file and it adds more paths to loadpath (without removing the ones already there)